# Launching the e-mail client from razor view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application in which I have this view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Template.cshtml";
}
@section logout {

    <a href='@Url.Action("Logout", "Begin")' style="margin-left: 91.3%"><img src="~/Content/images/images.jpg" style="width:37px; height:37px" /></a>
    }
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function mailJob(code) {
            window.open('mailto:example@gmail.com');
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

<form action="/Pages/Index" method="post" style="margin-left:20%">
    <div class ="CenterTitle">
        <h1 style="color:rgb(73, 140, 212)">Norm impact : Registre des réclamations clients</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="noPrint">
         <input type="hidden" value ="1" name="Pages"/>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnPage1"><img src="~/Content/images/OK.png" onclick="mailJob('Sample');"/></button>
                <button type="button" value="exportToPDF" onclick="window.print()" name="btnPage1"style="margin-left:55%"><img src="~/Content/images/print.png" /></button>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="noPrint">
        <button type="submit" value="Page2" name="btnPage1" style="margin-left:75%"><img src="~/Content/images/next.png" /></button>
    </div>
</form>

</body></html>
```

The problem is in the `mailto` because the mailing soft is not launching but a new window with this url `mailto:example@gmail.com`.

So how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function mailJob(code) {
    window.location.href = 'mailto:example@gmail.com';
}
```